# Why are these mesh white and does not appear in rendering?

Tags: mesh, color

I'm trying to edit this intro [image]https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fya4qXcCzeU, but the mesh contained in the intro does not appear in rendering, the mesh appears all white in preview.

In the video contains the link with the file blender.

Thanks to all who tried to help me

Cheers!

Comment: No addons are required to render, if an object doesn't show up check is visibility and renderability in the outliner. This has been asking countless times before here. Do a search or provide proper details and screenshots of your scene and setup.

Comment: We don't know what object you are talking about exactly.

Answer (score 0):

While you are in Object Mode press <kbd>W</kbd> and then *Clear All Restrict Render*. Hope it helped

Comment: unfortunately, your idea doesn't worked, because nothing changed. Thanks for trying to help me!